# Can I use Microsoft Chart Control in Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, mschart

Did some googling and couldn't find a clear answer on this.

My assumption is no if they are distributed in a binary form.

I currently use Dundas and would like to move away from a library that has a cost component, especially since the MS version has everything I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran the installer, available from [the download center on microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en).
Here are the terms of the license:

> Microsoft Corporation (or based on where you live, one of its affiliates) licenses this supplement to you.  You may use a copy of this supplement with each validly licensed copy of Microsoft Windows operating system  software (for which this supplement is applicable) (the “software”).  You may not use the supplement if you do not have a license for the software.  The license terms for the software apply to your use of this supplement.  Microsoft provides support services for the supplement as described at www.support.microsoft.com/common/international.aspx.

It doesn't say that you cannot use it with Mono.  It says that you **must** use it with (on) Windows.

Sounds like, *Yes, you can use it with Mono running on Windows.*  But I'm not a lawyer.

---

If you want a charting library for use on Mono+Linux, try an open source option, like 
[ZedGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx).

Comment: Agree, but what's the point of using mono on windows (except if you're a mono developer) ?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you call use and on what you call mono...

I can confirm it works with mono on Windows.
I can confirm that when you remove system.linq and system.xml from the web.config, it will run on VB.NET on Linux under mono. It will run on C# under Linux without modifiying the web.config.

But in both cases (on Linux) you have to use RenderType="BinaryStreaming", because else, it uses a temporary directory where it generates the chart image. The problem with that is it only accepts \ as directoryseparator (checks the tmp directory in the web.config file on startup), and Linux uses /, so you aren't able to get it up and running with any Linux temp directory, that's why you need to select BinaryStreaming..

But appart from that, it works wonderfully.
However, ZedChart is the better option anyway (has more options), except that ZedChart doesn't support any kind of 3d-chart, yet.

Answer (score 2):

As @Cheeso said, you can't use it with Mono, but not in Linux/Mac/...

This is a piece of the [Supplemental Redist License](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c) of Microsoft Charting

> C. Distribution Restrictions. You may not:
>
> - ...
> - **distribute Distributable Code to run on a platform other than the
>     Windows platform;**
> - ...

:-(