# Choosing a charting library in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mono, charts

I'm developing a Web site in ASP MVC and now I have to show statistics and charts. I have been reading some related posts, and in my opinion, the best choices seems to be:

- [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) with a [.NET helper](http://googlechartnet.codeplex.com/)
- [Microsoft chart controls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) for .NET

I have been reviewing them and, in my opinion, the look and feel of Microsoft charting is better. On the other hand, Google Chart has the advantage that is online. I really don't know which to use.

My questions are:

- Somebody could enumerate advantages and disadvantages of both?
- Do you know other option better than these ones?
- Do you know any incompatibility with Mono? I guess it would work, but I would like to confirm.

**Edit**: I tested Microsoft Charts in Mono/Linux and works fine (See answer below).

Comment: Do remember that Microsoft chart controls was never developed by Microsoft.  It - and the company that developed it - were bought by MS.  It was originally developed by Dundas: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2008/11/07/microsoft-chart-control-vs-dundas-chart-control.aspx

Comment: I'm doing a test. I will test MSCharts in Mono, and I will write here a comment saying if it works or not.

Comment: @Darin: My requeriments are 1) Support for ASP MVC 2) Work in Mono

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use some controls from DevExpress or some jQuery open source alternatives:

- jQuery Visualize Plugin
- Highcharts
- Flot
- jQuery Sparklines
- jqPlot

Article [Link](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/)

Comment: I love Highcharts!! Definitively I will use it for my development. In my opinion it has better look and feel than Infragistics, MSCharts and Google Charts and it's pure JavaScript. Full compatibility with Mono.

Comment: I have used Flot and really like it.

Answer (score 2):

I use Microsoft chart controls its easy to use, and its working good :) I dont know much about Google chart. But Microsoft chart controls is made by Microsoft for.NET

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba No onfortunely

Answer (score 2):

I have tested **Microsoft Charts** in **Mono 2.8/Linux** with **ASP.NET MVC** and it works fine.

I have followed this [great guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205223757/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092210-1.aspx).

The problem I'm afraid is that I cannot distribute it due the [Microsoft charting license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589175/can-i-use-microsoft-chart-control-in-mono) :-(

Answer (score 1):

I use jQuery plugins like [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) and [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html) for plotting and charts in ASP.NET MVC web applications.